# Getting NoRegionError on trying to connect to Athena database

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-athena

Following is my code in which I am trying to connect to the Athena database.

```
def get_records_from_athena(env,region):
    database = config_params[env]['globeahtenadatabase']
    query = queryconfig.athenaqueryglobe['globedataofathena']
    df = AthenaBase(region, 'saml', True).get_query_result(database, query)
    return df

class AthenaBase(AwsBase):
    def __init__(self, region, profile_name, should_create_session) :
        '''
            Creates instance of AthenaBase
            :param region: AWS region
            :param profile_name eg: "saml"
            :param should_create_session Boolean value specifying whether or not session should be created. Pass True if running locally
            :return:None
        '''
        super().__init__(region, "athena", profile_name, should_create_session)
        self.s3_obj = S3Base(region, profile_name, should_create_session)


def get_query_result(self, database, query_string):
    '''
        Returns Athena query result
        :param database database name in Athena
        :param query_output_path path inside the bucket eg: Athena_Query
        :return:None
    '''
    query_result_df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(
        sql=query_string
        , database=database
        , boto3_session=self.session
        , ctas_approach=False
        , use_threads=True)
    return query_result_df
```

I even tried passing region as hardcoded as follows

```
def get_records_from_athena(env,region):
    database = config_params[env]['globeahtenadatabase']
    query = queryconfig.athenaqueryglobe['globedataofathena']
    df = AthenaBase('us-east-1', 'saml', True).get_query_result(database, query)
    return df
```

But still I am getting No region error. Following is the AwsBase class which I am inheriting and using it in the above code. Not sure if it is creating an issue creating the client in boto 3.

```
class AwsBase:

    def __init__(self, region, resource, profile_name, should_create_session, config=None):
        """
            If you are running this locally then should_create_session should be True (Make sure you have logged in on ADFS, on your terminal)
        """
        self.region = region
        self.resource = resource
        self.profile_name = profile_name
        self.should_create_session = should_create_session
        self.session, self.client = self.getClient(region, resource, profile_name, should_create_session, config)


    def getClient(self, region, resource, profile_name, should_create_session, config):
        """
           If you are running this locally then should_create_session should be True (Make sure you have logged in on ADFS, on your terminal)
        """
        if should_create_session==True:
            session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile_name)
            client = session.client(service_name=resource, region_name=region, config=config)
        elif should_create_session==False:
            session = boto3.Session()
            client = boto3.client(service_name=resource, region_name=region, config=config)
        else:
            raise Exception("should_create_session should be boolean")
        return session,client
```

Following is the detailed error
File "C:\Users\ppathar.virtualenvs\market-data-quality-checks-OBE1rMIj\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py", line 218, in _compute_endpoint_config
return self._resolve_endpoint(**resolve_endpoint_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ppathar.virtualenvs\market-data-quality-checks-OBE1rMIj\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py", line 300, in _resolve_endpoint
return endpoint_bridge.resolve(
File "C:\Users\ppathar.virtualenvs\market-data-quality-checks-OBE1rMIj\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 381, in resolve
resolved = self.endpoint_resolver.construct_endpoint(
File "C:\Users\ppathar.virtualenvs\market-data-quality-checks-OBE1rMIj\lib\site-packages\botocore\regions.py", line 133, in construct_endpoint
result = self._endpoint_for_partition(
File "C:\Users\ppathar.virtualenvs\market-data-quality-checks-OBE1rMIj\lib\site-packages\botocore\regions.py", line 148, in _endpoint_for_partition
raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

Comment: what is your class AwsBase? The one you are inheriting

Comment: Added. Please check the edited question.

Comment: And could you post your error. Moreover in your first code block you have some indentation problems

Comment: Posted the detailed error

Comment: I ment in your line of code what line raised the error, your get_query_result is wrong indented. moreover how this method is using the client? what is `wr.` object?

Comment: That is wrangler